# Git LFS file not shown

Tags: github, pull-request, git-lfs

While, submitting my pull request on github I saw some of the images are displaying the message Git LFS file is not shown and I'm having all the images in my working branch.What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this problem maybe related your github settings for Git LFS.
Could you double check that it's enabled? 
[How to check Git Large File Storage Configuration](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.11/admin/guides/installation/configuring-git-large-file-storage-for-a-repository/)

These are the actual instructions on the link.

1. Sign in to your GitHub Enterprise instance at http(s)://[hostname]/login.
2. Rocketship icon for accessing site admin settingsIn the upper-right corner of any page, click the Rocketship icon.
3. Site admin settings search fieldIn the search field, type the name of the repository and click Search.
4. Site admin settings search optionsIn the search results, click the name of the repository.
5. Admin ToolsIn the upper-right corner of the page, click  Admin.
6. Admin ToolsIn the left sidebar, click Admin.
7. Disable buttonIn the Git LFS section, click Enable or Disable.

Comment: It is better to post details here than send users to different sites, even if you are just directly quoting from the link.